# Typescript: What does it mean by "class variable" of type "another class"

Tags: typescript

What does it mean when in the class we declare a variable at class level and give its type as another class like this

```
let greeter: Greeter;  //line 1
greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

Now what greeter has in it. What greeter contains in line 1

Answer (score 0):

first line ONLY declares a variable of type Greeter.(no instances here)
second line you initialize this variable with actual value and new instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyClass {
  let greeter; // if not given its any type
  constructor() {
    greeter = new Greeter("world");
  }

  someFunction() {
    greeter.someMethod(); //you wont have type here, thus no intellisense
  }

}
```